# rust folder structure organisation

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
src
 |-- abc
      |-- main.rs
 |-- logger
      |-- mod.rs
Cargo.toml
```

```
#Cargo.toml

[[bin]]
name = "abc"  # This will be the name of the binary executable
path = "src/abc/main.rs"
```

```
#logger/mod.rs

pub fn call_logger() {
    println!("Got called!");
}
```

I want to call this fn call_logger() from main.rs (abc/main.rs), how can I do so?
I tried this way,

I created lib.rs (src/lib.rs), contents of which is

```
#src/lib.rs
pub mod logger;
```

and I was able to call `call_logger()`.
Just want to know what is the right way to achieve the above task, as lib.rs is used for library crate ?

Comment: Why won't you use standard layout?

Comment: Is `call_logger` shared? Then it belongs somewhere in the hirarchy of the library crate, if not, it belongs in `main.rs` hierarchy. You must put a `mod logger;` somewhere!

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I don't get it can you elaborate please

Comment: @cafce25 actually I don't want to use lib.rs, so can I still be able to call call_logger()? is there any way

Comment: No, binary crates can't be shared.

Comment: "Standard layout" is the layout Cargo uses by default, with no configuration. Meaning, binary crates are either `src/main.rs` or under `src/bin`, library crate starts from `src/lib.rs` (it defines all `mod`s, it is the root) and all files under `src/**/*.rs` are its submodules.

Comment: See also https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/cargo/guide/project-layout.html.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to make this work.

1. [The `path` attribute](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/items/modules.html#the-path-attribute).

   If you only want a binary (no library), you can use the `path` attribute to specify where the module should be located:

   ```rust
   // In src/abc/main.rs
   #[path = "../logger/mod.rs"]
   mod logger;
   ```
2. Create a library.

   Create a file `src/lib.rs` and put in it:

   ```rust
   pub mod logger;
   ```

   Then, you can refer to the logger in the binary as `crate_name::logger`.